# Download GitLab file with gitlab-python

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

I am trying to download a file or folder from my gitlab repository, but they only way I have seen to do it is using CURL and command line. Is there any way to download files from the repository with just the python-gitlab API? I have read through the API and have not found anything, but other posts said it was possible, just gave no solution.

Comment: `id = [d['id'] for d in p.repository_tree() if d['name'] == 'README.rst'][0]` `file_content = p.repository_raw_blob(id)` [docs](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html)

Comment: @LeiYang is there a way to do it from a path to the file on gitlab? I have the exact path of the file I want to download. Also, what if I need to download an entire folder of files?

Comment: i suggest you use other libraries, such as [gitpython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/), or `requests` module to simulate curl. the [doc](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html) says gitlab-python even "doesn’t provide an API to clone a project".

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://<your_path>/file.txt')
data = response.text
```

and then save the contents (data) as file...

Otherwise use the API:

```
f = project.files.get(path='<folder>/file.txt',ref='<branch or commit>')
```

and then decode using:

```
import base64
content = base64.b64decode(f.content)
```

and then save content as file...